# Moment js diff function is not working in react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

In my react native application, I use moment js. I have the following code.

```
const expDate = moment(new Date(val)).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
const nowDate = moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY');
const diff = nowDate.diff(expDate, 'years');
console.log(diff);
```

But this says, diff is not a function. I tried few other methods, then I get a deprecation warning, saying RFC2822, format etc.

What am I doing wrong in above code?

Comment: You're calling `diff` on `nowDate` which is a string, diff before you format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your `val` is a string, you can create a moment directly from string by passing the format.

```
const expDate = Moment("06-30-2018", "MM-DD-YYYY"); // create moment from string with format 
const nowDate = Moment(); // new moment -> today 
const diff = nowDate.diff(expDate, 'days'); // returns 366 
const diff2 = nowDate.diff(expDate, 'years'); // returns 1
```

`.format` transforms your moment to a string that's why `.diff` does not work

**Working Expo:**

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/cranky-bagel

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `.format` after `.diff`.

## Correct

```js
    const expDate = moment(new Date("1999-02-18T00:00:00"));
    const nowDate = moment();
    const nowDateFormated = nowDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    const expDateFormated = expDate .format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    const diff = nowDate.diff(expDate, 'years');
    console.log(diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

## Wrong

```js
    const expDate = moment(new Date("1999-02-18T00:00:00"));
    const nowDate = moment();
    const nowDateFormated = nowDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    const expDateFormated = expDate .format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    const diff = nowDateFormated.diff(expDateFormated , 'years');
    console.log(diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `nowDate.diff(expDate, 'years')` returns an integer, that's why a `.format` fails

Comment: @Tim ops, my mistake, added a extra `.format` there